# spring mvc with rest webservices using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working with Customer application using Spring MVC with REstful webservice using Hibernate. I have created this application as a Dynamic web project in Eclipse because if i am using Maven i am getting few dependencies error.

As i am new to these technologies I don’t know where I have done mistake in configuring these files

I have configured as follows in configuration files.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee             
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"    version="3.0">

 <display-name>SpringWithRestCaseStudy</display-name>
 <context-param>
 <param-name>root-context</param-name>
     <param-value>\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet\root-  context.xml</paramvalue>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet-context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- class>
   <init-param>  
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
      <param-value>\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet\servlet-context.xml</param-value>  
   </init-param>    

 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>servlet-context</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
              xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
              xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema     /context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
<resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></resources>
<beans:bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.crud.rest.controllers" />
</beans:beans>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:c="htpp://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:p="htpp://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">  
</property>
<property name="url"  value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.156.152:1521:orcl">  
</property>
<property name="username" value="scott"></property>
<property name="password" value="tiger"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>com.crud.rest.beans.MyCustomer</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerDao" class="com.crud.rest.dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerService" class="com.crud.rest.dao.CustomerServiceImpl">
<property name="CustomerDao" ref="CustomerDao"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I am getting the error as follows.

```
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ShoppingDemo' did not find a matching property.
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringWithRestCaseStudy' did not find a matching property.
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.37.0
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b18
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Narmatha Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
   Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM     org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Narmatha      Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
     Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.37
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM     org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
     INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Narmatha  Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
     Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.37\endorsed
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~2\CA\SC\CAM\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ORACLEXE\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Tcl\bin;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\;C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
     Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool  getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1524 ms
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
     INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 12, 2017 12:52:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
   Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Marking servlet dispatcher as unavailable
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/ShoppingDemo]   threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      org.springframework.web.servlet.DisptacherServlet
     at   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB       ase.java:1333)
    at      org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB     ase.java:1167)
  at     org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceMana    ger.java:518)
   at    org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(Defa    ultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceMa    nager.java:118)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:109    1)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
   at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5    038)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5    348)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:140    7)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:139     7)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener at   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB     ase.java:1333)
at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB    ase.java:1167) at     org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518) at      org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceMa     nager.java:118)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4    775)
    at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5    314)
   at   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
   at   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) at   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:130 9) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext     listenerStart
     SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class   org.springframework.web.context.RequestContextListener
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.springframework.web.context.RequestContextListener
    at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB      ase.java:1333)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB    ase.java:1167)
 at    org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceMana    ger.java:518)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(Defa     ultInstanceManager.java:499)
   at  org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceMa  nager.java:118)
   at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4      775)
 at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5     314)
   at   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
     SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/SpringWithRestCaseStudy] startup failed due to previous errors
   Sep 12, 2017 12:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Sep 12, 2017 12:53:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 5154 ms
```

Kindly someone help me to solve this issue.

And it would be more helpful if someone can provide a details of how to configure these 3 files.

Comment: Looks like you miss spring-web in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Might this is solution.

The solution to this problem is very simple. Double click on your tomcat server. It will open the server configuration. Under server options check ‘Publish module contents to separate XML files’ checkbox. Restart your server. This time your page will come without any issues.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPeP4.png)